# Convert Pojo Components to EJB3

Tags: java, components, seam, ejb, pojo

I tried to use an extended `PersistenceContext` in a component by adding

```
@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager entityManager;
```

In order to use this Seam forces me to delcare the component as a Stateful Session Bean (SFSB). To meet the requirements I have to create an interface for SFSB's methods even the methods declared in `EntityHome<E>` and `Home<E>` is this the right (Seam)  way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a Seam point-of-view, it's OK using the extended `PersistenceContext`. You can also read these two references for pros and cons of using it: [When do I use @In vs @PersistenceContext to inject an EntityManager?](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhenDoIUseInVsPersistenceContextToInjectAnEntityManager) and 

[EntityManager injection: @PersistenceContext or @In ??](http://seamframework.org/Community/EntityManagerInjectionPersistenceContextOrIn).

Since `Home<E>` is conversation scoped, I would try to benefit from that scope to get an extended persistence context. Although, using an extended `PersistenceContext` is fine, the conversation scope this is definitely more the 'Seam-way'. However, since I'm not aware of what you want to accomplish, the conversation-scope might not be approperiate...

Comment: thanks for the good readings, I struggled with whether I should implement or read manuals ;-)